# Restriction kmeans in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cluster-computing, k-means

I have around dataset of 120+ patients, each patient contains different number of images. I created a matrix using these images, which looks like below:

```
              Histogram
  P1 Image 1  here is histogram
  P1 Image 2   //
  P1 Image 3   //
  P2 Image 1   //
  P2 Image 2   //
  P2 Image 3   //
  P2 Image 4   //
  and so on patient 3 and 4 upto 120.
```

I want kmeans with 80 clusters, to put at least one image of each patient in one cluster. ( Every cluster contains at least one image from each patient data set)

In matlab here is the simple code I used.\

```
  `idx = kmeans(matrix,80)`
```

And of course it does not doing the job, anyone please any tutorial or anything which might help me to achieve my goal. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you want each cluster to have at least one image of each patient and you have 120 patients, shouldn't you need a minimum of 120 clusters??

Comment: Edit : If k-means cannot assign 120 images of 120 different patients to each cluster, that means that the dataset of your histograms (features) is not grouped this way. Does all your histograms of Image 1 for example has the minimum distance between them respect with the other histograms of other images?? What is your correlation matrix looks like?

Comment: matalb ? you will find more answers with a right title